# How to iterate a vector from a map of vectors?

Tags: c++, stl

My map built from vectors, and I want iterate it, but I don't know how to do it !

```
  WayMap::iterator it;

  for ( it = MyWayMap.begin(); it != MyWayMap.end(); it++ ) 
// Loop the Whole Way Map
    {
      for(it->second.nodeRefList.begin();it->second.nodeRefList != it->second.nodeRefList.rbegin()-1;it->second.nodeRefList++);
// Loop The Whole Nodes of Each way
                }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: what is `it->second.nodeRefList.rbegin()-1` supposed to do? Also, comparing the container to an iterator is not really something I've ever seen done.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your inner loop doesn't make much sense to me. In initialization part (before first `;`) the result is discarded and not saved to any variable. In condition part (between two `;`) you try to compare `std::vector` and `reverse_iterator` and in the step part (after both `;`) you try to increment `std::vector`?

Comment: Maybe if you posted `WayMap`, we can tell you the *valid* ways it can be iterated over.  Right now, it seems your attempt looks like trying anything and hoping it works.

Comment: you should declare a variable (iterator) within the inner loop and work with it (similarly to `it` in the outer loop, maybe `innerit = it->second.nodeRefList.begin()`). You should compare it to `.end()`, not to `.rbegin() - 1`, and you should increment your declared inner iterator, `it->second.nodeRefList++` makes no sense. Also, you generally should pre-increment `++it` instead of post incrementing `it++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments give you all the hints you need already.

If we assume, that `it->second.nodeRefList` is a container (and not an iterator) and the line numbers correspond to the inner loop, the inner loop should look more or less like

```
for(auto j = it->second.nodeRefList.begin(); j != it->second.nodeRefList.end(); ++j)
    ; // do something with node iterator (j)
```

---

Better yet, use a [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for (auto &node : it->second.nodeRefList)
    ; // do something with node
```

---

To calculate the distance using consecutive elements, you could use two iterators moving in lockstep

```
auto &nodes = it->second.nodeRefList;
for (auto i1 = nodes.begin(), i2 = i1 + 1; i2 != nodes.end(); ++i1, ++i2) {
    auto dist = euclidean_distance(*i1, *i2);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Even better use a range-for for both loops. `for (auto & entry : MyWayMap) { for (auto & node : entry.second.nodeRefList) { ... } }`

Comment: I wanted to loop the victor to calculate the Euclidean distance between each Node and the following Node.

Comment: @BelalHomaidan Then you need to maintain two iterators, or save a reference to the previous node.